# How can I alter column type from int8 to bytes in cockroachdb?

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a very simple table namely:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT unique_rowid()
)
```

And I want to change `id` type to bytes so that I can `SET DEFAULT uuid_v4();`.

However if I run this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY id bytes;
```

I'm getting an error:
`pq: cannot convert INT8 to BYTES`

Is there a possibility to alter table column from one type to another in cockroachdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, cockroach doesn't allow alter primary key constraint, so what I did was simply create new table with appropriate PK type, used `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement, deleted old table and then renamed new one.

They have it in official documentation:

> A table's primary key can only be specified in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement. It cannot be changed later using ALTER TABLE, though it is
>   possible to go through a process to create a new table with the new
>   primary key you want and then migrate the data.

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/primary-key.html